# Can the hidden global attribute be changed with CSS?

Tags: html, css, show-hide

If I write:

```html
<div hidden>blah blah blah</div>
```

then the `<div>` is hidden. Can I make it visible by using just CSS? Or is there some other way to hide a `<div>` with just HTML that can be undone with CSS?

Comment: Of course there are other ways of hiding it, using the hidden attr. isn't really the way to go nowadays, instead rather choose: `display: none` / `display: block` **or** `visibility: hidden` / `visibility: visible`, pure CSS

Comment: @VXp The reason I didn't want to use CSS to hide it was that I'm aiming for the case when CSS is turned off. Is there by any chance some better, more modern way to do this without resorting to JavaScript?

Comment: @VXp Users can turn off CSS in their browsers and then I guess inline styles is a no go. Also, inline styles takes precedence over any stylesheets I could add so then the only way of showing the `div`again would be to edit the `style` attribute through JavaScript. And I don't want to do that. If there isn't any better way, then your proposed solution below should work perfectly.

Comment: Nope there isn't, true, but you don't have to worry or take into account that users will turn off the CSS, usually it's the JS.

Comment: @VXp Alright. This was more for curiosity than any practical relevance. But it's a small edit and it will make me happy so I might as well include it :-)

Comment: Sure, why not. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the `display` *property* of any *value* different than *none*:

```css
div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div hidden>blah blah blah</div>
```